# smtplib of python on netangels not working

Tags: python, smtplib

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email, password)
server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, text)
server.quit()
```

I have python script that send email letters via SMTP using python package smtplib
This script works on my local PC but when I uploaded this code to netangels virtual machine I got error
`OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable`
Help pls!
Thank u in advance!

I tried to use SSL connection with port 465 it works on my PC but on netangels it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

is outbund FW enabled for port on your netangels virtual machine to smtp.gmail.com?
Can you test ping dns or ip-address (smtp.gmail.com)? Or you can test example: Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "www.contoso.com" -Port 123
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your time that u spent for my question.
I asked netangels support about this a they said on tariffs of the START line SMTP disabled and I need to use any tariff starts from Tiny.

Hope on thaat this question will help somebody who face this problem!
Thank you!